# Set button inside one div same height as button in other div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 3 `divs` all aligned on one height on a page.

Inside those divs I have a title `h3`and below that an unordered list `<ul> <li>`.

Below the list I have a button that the user can click on to go to another page.

As the lists have different amounts of `<li>'s`, the button below them are at different heights, and I want everything to be on the same height.

I can manipulate the height of each div, so that they are the same as the heighest div using JS `getBoundingClientRect()`, but I am unsure how to set the positioning of the button so they align as well.

`HTML`

```
<div>
   <div class="three_divs">
       <h3>first title</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>one</li>
          <li>two</li>
          <li>three</li>
          <li>four</li>
          <li>five</li>
        </ul>
     <button>click here</button>
   </div>
   <div class="three_divs">
      <h3>second title</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>one</li>
          <li>two</li>
          <li>three</li>
        </ul>
     <button>click here</button>
   </div>
   <div class="three_divs"> 
      <h3>third title</h3>
         <ul>
           <li>one</li>
           <li>two</li>
         </ul>
      <button>click here</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.three_divs {display:inline-block; float: left; width: 30%;}
```

As I know that the first div is the highest, I simply get the height and set the other 2 after that to the same height. But how do i do this for the buttons?

I have thought of using `margin-top` of the button, but not sure how to calculate the distance. Open to CSS or JS (or even jQuery) solutions (or any solutions).

JS

```
function set_divs_height(){
let divs = document.getElementsByClassName("three_divs");
let first_div_height = divs[0].getBoundingClientRect().height;
for (let i = 1; i < 3; i++){
    divs[i].style.height = first_div_height + "px";
    }
}
set_divs_height()
window.onresize = function(){set_divs_height()};
```

Comment: You can achieve this with grid if you have access to it.

Answer (score 1):

As @Grumpy commented you can try with grid:

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}
.three_divs {
  display: grid;
  justify-items: center;
}

button {
  align-self: end;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   <div class="three_divs">
       <h3>first title</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>one</li>
          <li>two</li>
          <li>three</li>
          <li>four</li>
          <li>five</li>
        </ul>
     <button>click here</button>
   </div>
   <div class="three_divs">
      <h3>second title</h3>
        <ul>
          <li>one</li>
          <li>two</li>
          <li>three</li>
        </ul>
     <button>click here</button>
   </div>
   <div class="three_divs"> 
      <h3>third title</h3>
         <ul>
           <li>one</li>
           <li>two</li>
         </ul>
      <button>click here</button>
   </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Are you good to go with `flex` implementation? Then remove all the script, this will handle all the browser resize events.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}
.three_divs {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 30%;
}
.three_divs ul {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.three_divs button {
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="three_divs">
    <h3>first title</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
      <li>four</li>
      <li>five</li>
    </ul>
    <button>click here</button>
  </div>
  <div class="three_divs">
    <h3>second title</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
      <li>three</li>
    </ul>
    <button>click here</button>
  </div>
  <div class="three_divs">
    <h3>third title</h3>
    <ul>
      <li>one</li>
      <li>two</li>
    </ul>
    <button>click here</button>
  </div>
</div>
```